# Unsupported operation exception when adding or clearing elemetings of list

Tags: android

I have made a function in which i first add contacts one my one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        Contact contact = new Contact();
                        contact.setUserId(jsonObject.getString(ResponseParams.USER_ID));
                        contact.setPhoneNumber(jsonObject.getString(ResponseParams.PHONE_NUMBER));
                        contact.setUserName(jsonObject.getString(ResponseParams.USER_NAME));

                        ((TazligenApp) activity.getApplication()).getTazligenContacts().add(contact);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

but on the line:

((TazligenApp) activity.getApplication()).getTazligenContacts().add(contact);

i get unsupported operation exception and this obviously happens when i try to refresh contacts second time , Now i kinda know the reason but i don't know hwo to solve it.
P.S TazligenApp is my application class in android having some variables that i need throughout the cycle

Comment: You need to post more code, including how you're creating the contacts List, and the `getTazligenContacts()` method.

Comment: happened for the second time in a day , i found the answer myself :p
anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the answer myself , but i am posting my solution so it might help someone :)
Well i just created a temp list . Added my items in that list and then just put it equal to my other list like

```
forloop(){
    tempList.add(item);
}

mainList = tempList;
```

and it worked